# Consecutive pairs with recursion on haskell

Tags: haskell

I have this code:

```
pairs :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
pairs [] = []
pairs xs = zip xs (tail xs)
```

An example of what this code does:

```
> pairs "hey"
[('h','e'),('e','y')]
> pairs [1..7]
[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(6,7)]
```

I was wondering how to do this in recursive ways. I tried this,

```
pairs (x:xs) = (x,head xs): pairs xs
```

but it failed with the following exception

```
> pairs [1..7]
[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(6,7),(7,*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

Comment: Could you please stop using the `haskell-stack` tag for questions that don't involve `stack`? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can work with a pattern that selects the first two elements and recurses on the tail:

```
pairs :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
pairs [] = []
pairs [_] = []
pairs (x:xs@(x2:_)) = (x, x2) : pairs xs
```

or with less "unpacking":

```
pairs :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
pairs [] = []
pairs (x:xs) = go xs x
    where go [] _ = []
          go (x2:xs) x = (x, x2) : go xs x2
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your attempt is that it assumes `xs` to have at least one element or, in other words, the whole input `(x:xs)` to have at least two elements, so it fails when it reaches the end.

You can solve this by writing a special case for the one-element list before the "normal" case you've already written:

```hs
pairs :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
pairs [_] = []
pairs (x:xs) = (x,head xs):pairs xs
```

if you also need it to work on empty lists, then you need to keep also the `pairs [] = []` case.¹

(¹) Honestly, when I wrote the answer, I had already forgotten you were trying to emulate `zip xs (tail xs)`², so I haven't included the case for `[]` input.

(²)  By the way, you really don't need `pairs [] = []` in your `zip` version of the function, because `zip xs (tail xs)` works well with the empty list too, thanks to laziness.